# Kivy: How do I stop a scatter widget overlapping tab headers

Tags: python, kivy, scatter

A Scatter widget is positioned in a TabbedPanelItem content. When the scatter object is moved, it moves over all the tab headers. How do I make sure it moves under the tab headers? I get that widget depth index follows the order of when widgets are added, but don't understand how I could add the Scatter before the Tab widget to avoid this?

Image of problem:

Scatter widget overlapping tab headers

[image]

Code illustrating problem (scatter item is red, on tab 1):

```
from  kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

Builder.load_string("""

<TabbedTestScreen>:
    TabbedPanel:
        id: tab_panel
        do_default_tab: False
        tab_pos: 'left_top'
        tab_height: 90
        tab_width: 90

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '1'
            BoxLayout:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

                Scatter:
                    canvas.after:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: 1,0,0,0.5
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    auto_bring_to_front: False     # this doesn't make any difference
                    center: self.parent.center
                    size: self.parent.size
                    do_rotation: False
                    do_translation: True
                    do_scale: True
                    Label:
                        text: 'Tab 1 scatter widget'
                        font_size: 20
                        center: self.parent.center
                        size: self.parent.size

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '2'
            Label:
                text: '2'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '3' 
            id: home_tab
            Label:
                text: '3'                    

""")

class TabbedTestScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TabbedTestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

runTouchApp(TabbedTestScreen())
```

Comment: Works fine for me, also. I am using Python 3.6.1 with Kivy v1.10.0 under Ubuntu 16.04. What are you using?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Have you dragged the scatter?

Comment: @eyllanesc, no. Oops, I misread the OP.

Comment: @JohnAnderson That is what the author describes, the problem arises because when moving it and establishing in False the property auto_bring_to_front should be shown behind the tab, in theory, but it does not.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to this forum and would like to contribute more but don't have the rep yet... if you think this question and answer is useful to the community, would you consider upvoting? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is about widget ordering.

Kivy uses the order of widget insertion into the tree as z-index, (you always add "on top" by default), and the layouts and complex widgets also use this order as an indication of position, most of the time this is all good and fine, but sometime it's not and then you sometime you need weird workarounds.

That's happening here, TabbedPanel does a bit of magic and the headers are actually all "before" (so under) the container, and since your content can go outside of the intended zone, the effect is not what you'd expect.

The solution i'd advise here is to actually prevent the content to draw anything outside of its position, using a Stencil.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

Builder.load_string("""

<TabbedTestScreen>:
    TabbedPanel:
        id: tab_panel
        do_default_tab: False
        tab_pos: 'left_top'
        tab_height: 90
        tab_width: 90

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '1'
            BoxLayout:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

                canvas.before:
                    StencilPush
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                    StencilUse

                canvas.after:
                    StencilUnUse
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                    StencilPop

                Scatter:
                    canvas.after:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: 1,0,0,0.5
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    auto_bring_to_front: False     # this doesn't make any difference
                    center: self.parent.center
                    size: self.parent.size
                    do_rotation: False
                    do_translation: True
                    do_scale: True
                    Label:
                        text: 'Tab 1 scatter widget'
                        font_size: 20
                        center: self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2
                        size: self.parent.size

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '2'
            Label:
                text: '2'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '3' 
            id: home_tab
            Label:
                text: '3'

""")

class TabbedTestScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TabbedTestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

runTouchApp(TabbedTestScreen())
```

but then you still have an issue, while it's correctly not visible on the relevant places, the scatter is still active and can be grabbed, which makes for a confusing interface.

So you also want the BoxLayout not to care for touches outside of its position.

One would assume that something like StencilView would do this, but it doesn't, so you need a bit of work on your side.

```
from  kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.stencilview import StencilView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class StencilBox(StencilView, BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return
        return super(StencilBox, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return
        return super(StencilBox, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return
        return super(StencilBox, self).on_touch_up(touch)


Builder.load_string("""

<TabbedTestScreen>:
    TabbedPanel:
        id: tab_panel
        do_default_tab: False
        tab_pos: 'left_top'
        tab_height: 90
        tab_width: 90

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '1'
            StencilBox:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

                Scatter:
                    canvas.after:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: 1,0,0,0.5
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    auto_bring_to_front: False     # this doesn't make any difference
                    center: self.parent.center
                    size: self.parent.size
                    do_rotation: False
                    do_translation: True
                    do_scale: True
                    Label:
                        text: 'Tab 1 scatter widget'
                        font_size: 20
                        center: self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2
                        size: self.parent.size

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '2'
            Label:
                text: '2'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: '3' 
            id: home_tab
            Label:
                text: '3'

""")

class TabbedTestScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TabbedTestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

runTouchApp(TabbedTestScreen())
```

(i also fixed a small issue with the label position not being relative, since you are in a scatter, you need to use coordinates relative to the scatter, not the whole screen).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nails it ;-) Thanks for the explanation, makes good sense. I love the Stencil  View tool - didn't know about that at all - this clears up a lot of issues for me elsewhere too, as does the touch management.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but perhaps a start for someone who can take it further. If you use a custom `Scatter` like:

```
class MyScatter(Scatter):

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        parent = self.parent
        gparent = parent.parent
        if gparent is None:
            return
        ggparent = gparent.parent
        if ggparent is None:
            return
        num_children = len(ggparent.children)
        ggparent.remove_widget(gparent)
        ggparent.add_widget(gparent, num_children)
```

Extremely ugly, and has a side effect that I don't understand (tabs appear on the right). But the `MyScatter` object stays behind the tabs.

Comment: Hey thanks, whilst the side-effect was a showstopper for me in this app, I still learnt a bit from your code...